# Most efficient way to set Checkbox based on text file

Tags: android, performance

Currently I'm working on an Android app which will store preferences a list. When the user comes back after their first use they have the option to load their previous choices. However when I do this there is a several second delay while the loop runs. Is there a better way of going about this?

```
    if(stored)
     {
         CheckBox checkBox;
         ViewGroup viewGroup1 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.rightLayout);
         ViewGroup viewGroup2 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.leftLayout);
         String[] preferences = fileReadIn().split(",");
         String checkBoxText;
         String preferenceText;
         for(int i = 0; i < preferences.length; i++)
         {
             preferenceText = preferences[i].toLowerCase();
             for(int c = 0; c < viewGroup1.getChildCount(); c++)
             {
                 checkBox = (CheckBox) viewGroup1.getChildAt(c);
                 checkBoxText = checkBox.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
                 if(preferenceText.equals(checkBoxText))
                 {
                     checkBox.setChecked(true);
                 }
             }
             for(int c = 0; c < viewGroup2.getChildCount(); c++)
             {
                 checkBox = (CheckBox) viewGroup2.getChildAt(c);
                 checkBoxText = checkBox.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
                 if(preferenceText.equals(checkBoxText))
                 {
                     checkBox.setChecked(true);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to store your preferences in file. Android already provides an easier and faster way to store & retrive them. Refer to the [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) documentation

Here's a small example, if you want to store the value:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("preferences", myString);
editor.apply();
```

And when you want to retrieve, just use,

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String myString= prefs.getString("preferences", null);
if (myString != null) {
   //do whatever you want with it
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will adjust the project to use stored preferences instead.